# how to avoid automatically adding header files after complete in Youcompleteme

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I'm using `vim` on `ubuntu 16.04` platform, I found the `Youcompleteme` plugin always automatically add some unnecessary header file.

A simple example like I use `libtorch`, the `torch/torch.h` header file contains all headers the package needed, and don't need specifying any other related header. Just like the pictures below:

[image]

The completion works well, but after I use space select the completion, the unwanted header `torch/nn/module.h>` was added automatically.
[image]

I want to get a configure to disable automatically adding header files like this.

Any reply will be appreciated!

Comment: And old question, but for someone else looking for this or other `youcompleteme`-related topics, the best places to ask are listed in the _Help, Advice, Support_ section of [YouCompleteMe](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe), which has a link to the [contacts](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe#contact).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I stumbled upon this problem when I switched from libclang based YCM to clangd based. The guys on the community chat helped to figure out the solution: you can add the following line into your ~/.vimrc file:

```
let g:ycm_clangd_args=['--header-insertion=never']
```

Read `:help g:ycm_clangd_args` and `./clangd --help-list` for details on these options. It turns out there are plenty of cool configuration tweaks for clangd.